# ContainerHolderSinglton.getContainerHolder().getContainer() becomes null when resume app after some time

Tags: android

when we resume app  after some time ContainerHolderSinglton.getContainerHolder().getContainer() becomes null

Comment: without code/logcat, we can't help you

Answer (score 0):

I assume this happens when your app is in the background for some time, and you come back to the application.

This happens because your App's process gets killed as Android system need resources.

You should save all the variables you want restored in the onSaveInstanceState() method of your Activity / Fragments. You should save the variables inside the singletons and restore them in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method, from the savedInstanceState.

[Android Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)